# Как лучше подключаться к PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, flask

Есть WEB-приложение написанное на Python3/Flask, которое использует СУБД PostgreSQL. Допустим пользователь открывает страницу http://mysite.ru/ и в этот самый момент серверное python приложение делает серию запросов в PostgreSQL для генерации страницы-ответа

Что лучше и почему:

1. каждый раз подключаться к СУБД, делать запрос, получать ответ и отключаться;
2. создать одно подключение к СУБД при запуске приложения и все запросы выполнять через него одного

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Архитектурно PostgreSQL ориентирован на небольшое число долгоживущих соединений. И речь здесь не столько о накладных расходах на открытые tcp соединения и прохождение аутентификации, сколько о внутреннем устройстве этой СУБД. Так, при открытии нового соединения порождается отдельный процесс операционной системы через вызов `fork`. И уже всего на сотнях `fork` в секунду очень заметно растёт CPU sys time и проседает отзывчивость системы. А что такое 300 rps для веба? Это немного.

Затем, каждый backend процесс базы (т.е. который непосредственно обслуживает соединение и выполняет запросы) сохраняет в своем private памяти кучу всякого полезного, от кэша системного каталога до байткода хранимых процедур.

А так же в сегменте разделяемой памяти поддерживаются разные структуры необходимые для согласования работы параллельных процессов.

Поэтому в живую PostgreSQL используется только с пулом коннектов. На стороне приложения либо внешним таким как `pgbouncer`. То есть устанавливается до N соединений непосредственно с базой данных (обычно пул держит соединения сообразно необходимости, от 0 и до некоторого разумно сконфигурированного предела числа параллельных запросов которые ваша база может обработать). Приложение берёт коннект из пула когда ему это требуется и возвращает обратно после того как выполнило необходимые запросы.

Нередко используются оба: и пул на приложении и внешний пул pgbouncer, что позволяет лучше уплотнить коннекты базы, например, если у вас 2 сервера приложения.

> каждый раз подключаться к СУБД, делать запрос, получать ответ и отключаться;
>   создать одно подключение к СУБД при запуске приложения и все запросы выполнять через него одного

Или, отвечая точно на предложенные варианты: вариация второго пункта, но не с одним коннектом, а с некоторым их количеством.